# Вывод цитаты из массива

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо реализовать вывод цитаты из массива. Имеется такой блок `<div class="motivation"></div>`. Как можно вывести рандомную заготовленную цитату из массива в блок motivation?

```js
var myArray = ['Цитата 1', 'Цитата 2', 'Цитата 3', 'Цитата 4', 'Цитата 5'];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
var concat = myArray[rand];

function random() {
  var text = document.getElementsByClassName('motivation');
  text.write = (concat);
}
```

```html
<div class="motivation"></div>
```

Comment: Покажи маcсив @daniil-lav

Comment: `var myArray = ['Цитата 1', 'Цитата 2', 'Цитата 3', 'Цитата 4', 'Цитата 5'];    

var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);

var concat = myArray[rand];

function random() {
    $text = document.getElementsByClassName('motivation')
   $text.write = (concat);
}`

Я пытался реализовать таким способом, но у меня не получилось

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var text = document.getElementsByClassName('motivation'); // Выбрали элементы с классом

// Проходим по каждому элементу
Array.prototype.forEach.call(text, function(elem) {
  var myArray = ['Цитата 1', 'Цитата 2', 'Цитата 3', 'Цитата 4', 'Цитата 5'];
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length);
  var concat = myArray[rand];
  elem.innerHTML = concat; // Запись в блок
});
```

```html
<div class="motivation"></div>
<div class="motivation"></div>
<div class="motivation"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = ['Цитата 1', 'Цитата 2', 'Цитата 3', 'Цитата 4', 'Цитата 5']; 
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * myArray.length); 
var concat = myArray[rand];
$('.motivation').text(concat);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="motivation"></div>
```